ow to properly layout similar header blocks
Help please, I can’t understand how to correctly lay out such a block in the header, there is a container (1440px doesn’t matter) inside of which there is a logo pressed to the left side, how to make it so that behind the logo there is an img or gif that stretches across the entire logo container and also stretches to the left, I have attached an example of what it looks like.
enter image description here
I tried to do this through position and moved the img outside the container, but I couldn’t attach it to the logo

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I expect your logo is an anchor and it contains the logo image.
You can add a pseudo-element to the anchor, adjust its width to add the padding to align it the way you want, and apply the pattern image as a background.
.logo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.logo::before {
  background: url("path/to/image.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: -2vw; /* padding offset */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 4vw);
}

